# how to create virtual files system: BLL and attach it to UI?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, user-interface

I want to write a website that is basically like MS skydrive.
Meaning it will show UI of folders and files (no real storage, just links to cloud sources).

I wrote in C# a data-stracture of Tree (not binary) that depic the folders and files nesting.

How can I attach it to UI?
Does Jquery.IU can help me?
Any other tool/platform you would suggest?

Answer (score 0):

For this I would suggest you to go for Silverlight WebApp. Check out this http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Loading-Files-From-a-Remote-Server-in-Silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have a variety of options here.

- You can use WebForms and bind your model classes to a control like a ListView or a Repeater (or 3rd party tree view controls).
- You can use your classes as a Model for MVC views and display your file views in whatever way you like.
- You can create JSON or AJAX services that return your classes to the client and build your UI with jQuery or just plain JS.

Comment: I think to go for the 3rd option. What jQueryUI can help me?